# SWT ScrolledComposite Does Not Scroll for Big Composites

Tags: java, swt

We have a `ScrolledComposite` with lots and lots of child composites. For whatever reason, it won't scroll past about 30,000 pixels.

Here a snippet to show the problem. At least at this PC the last button I'm able to scroll to is #66.

```
public class ScrollBug {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        final ScrolledComposite scroller = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL);
        final Composite composite = new Composite(scroller, SWT.BORDER);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        composite.setSize(400, 50_000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            final Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
            button.setText("button #" + (1 + i)); //$NON-NLS-1$
            button.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().hint(-1, 500).create());
        }

        scroller.setContent(composite);
        scroller.layout(true, true);

        shell.setSize(600, 300);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

What's the problem (I'm guessing: Windows)? How do we overcome it?

Comment: You probably hit the [Limit of Logical Coordinate System in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/39802). To overcome this depends on what you actually want to display. Can you give some more details on what you need to display?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Bummer. We have composites showing diagrams, and evidently it's a use case for our customers to want to show 96 of them at a time (and they need them to be on top of each other). So each time the diagrams get to big, we run into that bug.

Comment: I can confirm that this isn't an issue on linux (Linux Mint).

Comment: To work around the limitation you could implement a _virtual_ container that creates just as many diagrams as fit in the height of the container and exchanges the content of the diagrams as the user scrolls.
It is unlikely that creating 96 diagrams (if it was possible) would lead to a responsive UI, and thus you would have to reconsider the current approach anyway.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann That's what we figured as well. I added the code for the component I created. But for whatever reason the UI is responsive even when there are that many diagrams, that's why the Windows restriction came completely out of the blue for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We thought the best approach would be a virtual composite as well, that's what I implemented yesterday. Even though it does not work 100 percent yet (much less with the diagrams we wanted, because of precious ancient code), maybe this will help the next person:

```
public class VirtualComposite extends Composite {

private final Composite content;
private final Slider scrollBar;
private final Map<Integer, Control> controls = new HashMap<>();

private VirtualCompositeModel model;

public VirtualComposite(final Composite parent, final int style) {
    super(parent, style);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    this.content = createContent();
    this.scrollBar = createScrollBar();
    hookListeners();
}

private Composite createContent() {
    final Composite result = new Composite(this, SWT.NONE);
    result.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).create());
    result.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    return result;
}

private Slider createScrollBar() {
    final Slider result = new Slider(this, SWT.VERTICAL);
    result.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().create());
    return result;
}

private void hookListeners() {
    final Listener updateContentListener = new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
            updateContent();
        }
    };
    this.scrollBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, updateContentListener);
    addListener(SWT.Resize, updateContentListener);
}

public VirtualCompositeModel getModel() {
    return this.model;
}

public void setModel(final VirtualCompositeModel model) {
    disposeAllControls();
    this.model = model;
    updateControlsFromModel();
}

protected void disposeAllControls() {
    if (this.model != null) {
        disposeControlsIfNecessary(0, this.model.getSize());
    }
}

protected void updateControlsFromModel() {
    updateScrollBarFromModel();
    updateContent();
}

private void updateScrollBarFromModel() {
    if (this.model != null) {
        final int entireHeight = getEntireHeight();
        // I have no idea whats wrong with the slider, but it needs +10
        this.scrollBar.setMaximum(entireHeight + 10);
    }
}

protected void updateContent() {
    if (this.model == null) {
        return;
    }
    final int position = this.scrollBar.getSelection();
    final int firstIndex = calculateIndex(position);
    int lastIndex = calculateIndex(position + getSize().y);

    if (lastIndex == -1) {
        lastIndex = this.model.getSize() - 1;
    }

    if (firstIndex != -1 && lastIndex != -1) {
        createControlsIfNecessary(firstIndex, lastIndex);
        disposeControlsIfNecessary(firstIndex, lastIndex);
        sortControls();
        updateContentIndent(firstIndex);
        layout(true, true);
    }
}

private int calculateIndent(final int index) {
    final int currentHeight = getHeight(index);
    return currentHeight - this.scrollBar.getSelection();
}

private int calculateIndex(final int position) {
    int currentHeight = 0;
    final int size = this.model.getSize();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        currentHeight += this.model.getHeightAt(i);
        if (position < currentHeight) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private void createControlsIfNecessary(final int firstIndex, final int lastIndex) {
    for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
        createControlIfNecessary(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
}

private void createControlIfNecessary(final Integer index) {
    if (!this.controls.containsKey(index)) {
        createControl(index);
    }
}

private void createControl(final Integer index) {
    final Control control = this.model.createElementAt(this.content, index.intValue());
    this.controls.put(index, control);
}

private void disposeControlsIfNecessary(final int firstIndex, final int lastIndex) {
    for (int i = 0; i < firstIndex; i++) {
        disposeControlIfNecessary(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    final int size = this.model.getSize();
    for (int i = lastIndex + 1; i < size; i++) {
        disposeControlIfNecessary(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
}

private void disposeControlIfNecessary(final Integer index) {
    if (this.controls.containsKey(index)) {
        disposeControl(index);
    }
}

private void disposeControl(final Integer index) {
    final Control control = this.controls.get(index);
    control.dispose();
    this.controls.remove(index);
}

private void sortControls() {
    final Control[] controlArray = createControlsArray();
    for (int current = 0; current < controlArray.length; current++) {
        for (int belowThat = current; belowThat < controlArray.length; belowThat++) {
            controlArray[current].moveAbove(controlArray[belowThat]);
        }
    }
}

private void updateContentIndent(final int firstIndex) {
    ((GridData) this.content.getLayoutData()).verticalIndent = calculateIndent(firstIndex);
}

protected Control[] createControlsArray() {
    final Control[] result = new Control[this.controls.size()];
    int index = 0;
    final int size = this.model.getSize();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        final Integer bigI = Integer.valueOf(i);
        if (this.controls.containsKey(bigI)) {
            result[index++] = this.controls.get(bigI);
        }
        if (index >= result.length) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public int getEntireHeight() {
    if (this.model == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return getHeight(this.model.getSize());
}

public int getHeight(final int count) {
    if (this.model == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result += this.model.getHeightAt(i);
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

And the model:

```
public interface VirtualCompositeModel {

int getSize();
int getHeightAt(int index);
Control createElementAt(Composite parent, int index);

}
```

It's used like that:

```
    VirtualComposite result = new VirtualComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    result.setModel(new VirtualCompositeModel() {

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public int getHeightAt(int index) {
            return 500;
        }

        @Override
        public Control createElementAt(Composite p, int index) {
            final Button button = new Button(p, SWT.PUSH);
            button.setText("Button #" + (1 + index)); 
            button.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).hint(-1, BUTTON_HEIGHT).create());
            return button;
        }
    });
```

Comment: if I got this right your solution can only be applied with static heights or heights known before hand. If the model elements have variable heights which you do not know before hand this will not be sufficient.

Comment: @lolung Yes, that's true. It might still work if you call the controls' `c.computeSize()` method to  let them calculate how much space they are going to need.

Comment: this is only possible when you already registered a control to be laid out by the underlying layout which actually computes the size (in your model ```createElementAt```). This means that the control is already created in the UI which is what you actually want to avoid with virtual or lazy loading.